# Вывести данные с разбивкой по месяцам

Tags: mysql

В таблице данные хранятся с привязкой по времени. Но время в unixtime. Как можно составить SQL-запрос, чтобы данные выводились примерно так:

- Июль

  - Строка1
  - Строка2
- Июнь

  - Строка3
  - Строка4

и так далее?

Данные хранятся с 2000 года,так что делать 216 запросов не вариант.

Comment: А почему бы это не сделать не в mysql, а в коде приложения?

Comment: То есть возвращать так же кучу, а там ее уже раскидывать?

Comment: Ну к примеру `ORDER BY date DESC` - это  если в запросе, а так, можно и уже после вывода сортировать по дате.

Comment: сначала решите как данные должны выглядеть в строго прямоугольном виде, потому что SQL всегда возвращает только плоскую таблицу. наиболее правильным будет сделать "Июль - строка1", "Июль - строка 2", а уже в дерево Июль и под ним две строки со сдвигом вправо - уже делать на клиенте. А что до определения, что это июль, то в MySQL воспользуйтесь функциями from_unixtime и date_format

Comment: Не совсем вас понял

Comment: Не путайте получение данных с сервера и их отображение на экране. То, что Вы хотите - это второе. И MySQL тут не при чём, ибо он свою работу (отправку клиенту данных - так, как @Mike указал) уже выполнил. Форматируйте полученное в своём приложении.